# Biopython+File IO operation - TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Tags: python, file-io, biopython

I tried to read a FASTA file using Biopython and write it again to another file before doing actual processing of the sequence.

```
w.write('Length of the Ref Seq: '+ ref_seq + ' is '+ str(len(ref_seq))+'\n')
```

TypeError: expected a character buffer object

I got the error mentioned above. Could someone please help me in understanding the error?

Thank you.

Comment: Everything looks fine , are you sure that `ref_seq` is of type string ?

Comment: The problem is probably that `ref_seq` is of type `Bio.Seq`, `str(ref_seq)` should do the trick.

Comment: @anmol_uppal ref_seq is the variable having the sequence read from the fasta file.

Comment: @cnluzon Thanks, I will try it. What does Bio.Seq type mean ? Is it another type of variable like string, integer?

Comment: @Prradep `Seq` is a class implemented by `Biopython`. It basically includes a `string` containing the sequence itself, along with the associated alphabet, depending on the type of sequence you are using (could be DNA, RNA, protein). More info about it can be found in the Biopython documentation: http://biopython.org/wiki/Seq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code solves the problem

```
from Bio import SeqIO
in_file = open("input.fasta")
records = SeqIO.parse(in_file, format="fasta")
out_file = open("output.txt", "w")
for mySeq in records:
  out_file.write('Length of the Ref Seq: '+ str(mySeq.seq) + 
                 ' is '+ str(len(mySeq.seq))+'\n')

out_file.close()
```

input.fasta:

> >165613
>
> TAACTGCAGTGTTTTGTGTCGAGC
>
> >165875
>
> GGGATCTTCGGACCTCGT

you get following output

> Length of the Ref Seq: TAACTGCAGTGTTTTGTGTCGAGC is 24
>
> Length of the Ref Seq: GGGATCTTCGGACCTCGT is 18

Comment: Thank you for the example and solution.